# How to use the deploy token correctly

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I will use the gitlab container registry for a private docker image. When the project is public I can download the docker image with `docker login registry.gitlab.com/user/jupyterhub`

Is the project private so I need a DEPLOY TOKEN. and a PASSWORD

PASSWORD = **KzErTBKAnwNEpxwVWU9g**
DEPLOY USER = **gitlab+deploy-token-28155**

`docker login registry.example.com -u gitlab+deploy-token-28155   -p KzErTBKAnwNEpxwVWU9g` and I can login into the registry

I get two warnings. How do I solve this problems?

> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
>   WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/klein/.docker/config.json.
>   Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

When I set in the Variables CI_DEPLOY_USER and CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD then gitlab ask for a password.
`docker login registry.gitlab.com -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the warning that your *password* is getting stored, you have to pass it via **stdin**:

```
echo $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER --password-stdin registry.gitlab.com
```